# How to access and change selectColumns core method inside react-handsontable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

I want to know that, how to access selectColumns menthod inside react-handsontable. I already tried to assign refs to hot table component `<HotTable refs="hot"/>` but still i cant access selectColumns method.

Thanks for reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sagar Any other approaches? It's not so convenient if we include HotTable in other components and can't render it in such way.
If we speak about this rows from example

```
const exampleComponent = ReactDOM.render(
<ExampleComponent />, document.getElementById('example')
);
window.hotInstance = exampleComponent.refs.hot.hotInstance;
```

it's okay, when we render it as a separate component. But if I import it in App component and then render App component via ReactDom.render, I have no refs, just empty object

Comment: I search for another approach but still i am looking for best way to access core methods. Some methods are accessible inside inside <HotTable> component this variable.